# Android: Add view Programmatically at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, view, addition

Is there a way to add a view programmatically at the bottom of the screen(no matter what size the screen is)? I dont need any work arounds or solutions with xml and/or layouts, just programmatically find the bottom of the screen and place a view there inside an activity .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I dont need any work arounds or solutions with xml and/or layouts -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: Actually you do this exactly by using xml defined layout, which you refuse to do.
I can only suggest adding a child to a FrameLayout for example. Explain why XML is no good here?

Comment: Thing is I have a parent activity with a activity_main.xml and another activity that inherits from the parent with a activity_blabla.xml. the parent activity contains a layout called content and in there programatically loads the activity_blabla.xml, so puting a view inside activity_blabla bottom wont end up at the bottom of the screen cause activity_main will place other stuff below .. What i want is in this specific activity to place something in the bottom . Please no work arounds like adding this view on acvity_main .. I need to know if what I asked is possible only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer , Ill post it here in case someone else will need this.

```
//find screen size
       Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getSize(size);
       int height = size.y;



  //set layout margin top depeding on screen size
  layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.theViewForTheBottom);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
       params.setMargins(0, height , 0, 0); 
       layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Note that if the view you want to place at the bottom does not start at the Top of the screen, you will have to do this process calculating dp distance from top , removing it from screen size in dp , and then setting the marging

Answer (score 0):

`View view = new View(this)` creates the new view

`layout.addView(view)` should add the view at the bottom. You could also add LayoutParams to set width/height, or to add rules like the `layout_below`.

Comment: This implies that the OP knows the proper layout rules for the container in question, which may be difficult to determine on the fly at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_views);
 // This is in your xml
 LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.footer);
 // Now we will create dynamic footer 
 final LinearLayout dynamic_footer=new LinearLayout(this);
 dynamic_footer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.Horizontal);
 ll.addView(dynamic_footer);
 Button add_btn=new Button(this);
 add_btn.setText("I am footer button");
 dynamic_footer.addView(add_btn);

 TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
 tv.setText("Hello World");
 dynamic_footer.addView(tv);
 EditText et=new EditText(getApplicationContext());
 dynamic_footer.addView(et); 

 }
```